# Occasional SSL problems on private WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, browser, lan, ssl

Once in a while I would get a problem like this:

[image]

It happens to any website (e.g., even in Gmail). After a few hours the problem's gone even if I didn't do anything to fix it. What could be causing this?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  The error is caused by Chrome using an invalid certificate.  Most often that is caused by a proxy being used.

Comment: @IMB:  Ramhound is right, but the problem could be as simple as a bad wifi connection.  You should try to reproduce it with a wired connection and if the problem isn't present anymore, troubleshooting needs to focus on wifi issues.

Comment: @JuliePelletier: I'm pretty sure that  ERR_CERT_INVALID can not be caused by a bad wifi. The client is obviously receiving a certificate bad does not like it.

Comment: @IMB: look at the certificate details and post the information here, i.e. who signed the certificate. Make sure that you are still connected to your own WiFi and not some other WiFi.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich:  With such a level of clarity in the question, we can't even know what network he is actually connected to.

Comment: Protip: Tapping the "ERR_CERT_INVALID" error will show the actual certificate.